# Aligning text to checkbox, can't seem to get it to align properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to align the text next to the checkbox on this page, however I can't seem to get it to work:

Here's a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbmnf/8/

**What I've tried:**

- Wrapping the text in a selector called `#blank_referrer .text` then;

  - Applying a negative `margin-top` and `padding-top`.
  - Applying `float: left;` on both the checkbox and text selector, which completely ruined the display.
  - Applying `display: inline-block;`.
  - Applying `line-height: 13px` (the height of the font) to `#blank_referrer`.

It's really annoying me that the checkbox isn't vertically aligned to the centre of the capital "T" in the text.

Any edits, answers, advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS definition:

```
#blank_referrer input[type="checkbox"] {
   display: block;
   margin: 1px 4px 0 0;
   float: left;
}
```

You can now tinker with the `margin-top` setting to get the look you want...

Comment: Or [float both of them](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbmnf/33/). Please, please use labels though (associated with the inputs like I have for the checkbox in the fiddle), esp. if you're putting the descriptions after the inputs. Screenreader users will thank you.